# What Lion maintenance utility should I use?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, maintenance

Im a huge fan of AppleJack, but I realize it doesn't currently support Lion.  What is an lion supported equivalent?

Im looking for a one-stop shop for all my Mac cleaning needs!

Bonus marks for software that can be deployed an managed remotely (on the same LAN)..

Thanks in advance!

Dev

Comment: Why do you think you need to use any "maintenance utility"?

Answer (score 2):

### [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/download.php?sid=0c5803d09bf388f117c6541230f533e8)

I don't know AppleJack, therefore I don't know if this program is sufficient for your needs. Onyx is a free tool for general system maintenance.

- You can **automize tasks** which you do frequently.
- Verify the Startup Disk and the structure of its System files, to run misc. tasks of system maintenance
- Delete caches, to remove a certain number of files and folders that may become cumbersome, and more.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to find a utility that can function as a true one stop shop for me, but here are three programs that I never leave home without, any one of which may come close to your needs.

[Cocktail](http://www.maintain.se/cocktail)

- Great day to day maintenance utility
- Lots of basic to moderate options
- Dead simple automation and scheduling for routinely performed tasks

[TechTool Pro](http://www.micromat.com/techtoolpro)

- Many similar functions to Cocktail but with more in depth system monitoring and trouble shooting options
- Expanded Disk Utility options compared to Cocktail
- Great for diagnosing problems you didn't even know you had

Disk Warrior  "http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/index.html"

- The "Delta Force" of disk utility apps
- Your First, Last, and Best line of defense for any disk related problem
- Complete re-construction of failed and lost directories and partitions.

Also, for what it's worth, I too find Onyx to be a great program as well, it's just never found it's way into my permanent arsenal.  Hope this gives you  a leaping off point.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys...

I appreciate the help and suggestions, I think I will tinker with Cocktail.  Is there anyway to run a disc repair on a mounted disc (such as your system drive while mounted and running) in Cocktail or any other utility?

Dev